# Finger Print Data Sharing With Other Android Devices

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

How can I share the fingerprints of many users with other Android devices? For example, we don't want to use fingerprint devices. We want to use Android devices for fingerprint control. The user will save the personal fingerprint in our application and when users use our application in other Android devices can they log in with these fingerprints? It's possible?

Comment: Apps do not have access to the fingerprint data read by the built-in fingerprint sensor.

Answer (score 0):

fingerprint module is kept apart from the android system for complete security. we cannot use android functions to access it. It is completely managed by the hardware.